# Different ways to pronounce "augh"

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, orthography, history

In the word *laugh*, it is pronounced "aff".
In the word *naught*, it is pronounced "aw".

Are there any other ways to pronounce "augh"?
Bonus points for etymology explaining from where these pronunciations come.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real bugger here is *-ugh*, plus a preceding vowel. The variants are:

- [ɔf] - *cough*
- [ӕf] - *laugh*
- [ӕu] - *bough*
- [u] - *through*
- [o] - *though*
- [ɔ] - *bought, naught*

The problem with all of these is the sound formerly pronounced as [x], which has disappeared in Modern English. The *way* that it disappeared, though, was variable. In most cases it simply vanished, mutating the vowel preceding it in various ways, with further vowel mutations influenced by a following consonant. This was what happened in *through, though, bought*, etc.

The unusual case is the words in which *-ugh* represents [f]. This is, alas, an **irregular** sound change. The ordinary outcome of the Old English form of *laugh* would be something pronounced like *law*, but for irregular and unpredictable reasons the [x] became [f] in this case.

Comment: In the UK at least, *slough* does not rhyme with *through* (*slough* rhymes with *fluff*, or *cow*, depending on the meaning), and *bough* does not rhyme with *though* (*bough* rhymes with *cow*) - and according to Merriam-Webster [bough](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bough) rhymes with [cow](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cow) and not [though](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/though?show=0&t=1302118053) even in the US.

Comment: @psmears, you're right about *bough*, which I've corrected above. However, I believe that there are at least *three* different ways that *Slough* can be pronounced: [slu], [slʌf], and [slaʊ], depending on what you're referring to. To avoid that issue, I've removed it brough the list above.

Comment: Yep - again, this is a regional variation thing - in the UK *slough* has just the two pronunciations; in (most of) the US it has three (again, if M-W is to be believed :)

Comment: In the US, depending on where you are, the word *slough* meaning "a muddy hollow, swamp, or inlet" is pronounced either [slu] or [slaʊ]. I would have thought that the meaning "a state of depression" would be pronounced the same way, being a metaphor of the first meaning. The American Heritage Dictionary agrees with this  (or at least it says either pronunciation is valid for both of these meanings), unlike Merriam-Webster. If it means shedding a skin, *slough* is pronounced [slʌf], just as in the UK

Answer (score 2):

What about **braugh** in the phrase [*Erin go braugh*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erin_Go_Bragh), described by Wikipedia as an anglicisation of the Irish *Éirinn go Brách*?  Does that work?  It's pronounced as "bra", with a bit of a trill on the "r".

Comment: I wonder if instead of "bra", this word might also be pronounced as "braw" (the same vowel as in "naught"). Irish á seems to often be anglicized as /ɔː/, like in the name Seán = "Shawn" (the pronunciation of á is also discussed more on this [Wikipedia talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Irish_phonology/Archive_1#a.CB.90_vs._.C9.91.CB.90.2C_.C9.92.CB.90.2C_or_.C9.94.CB.90))

Answer (score 1):

From my dictionary (I also put the ones you mentioned):

- **caught** |kôt| - ORIGIN: Middle English (also in the sense [chase]): from Anglo-Norman French and Old Northern French cachier, variant of Old French chacier, based on Latin captare ‘try to catch,’ from capere ‘take.’
- **naught** |nôt| - ORIGIN: Old English nāwiht, -wuht, from nā [no] + wiht [thing] (see wight).
- **laugh** |laf| - ORIGIN: Old English hlæhhan, hliehhan, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch and German lachen, also to laughter.
- **aught**  |ôt| - ORIGIN: Old English āwiht (see aye, wight).
- **daughter** |ˈdôtər; ˈdä-| - ORIGIN: Old English dohtor, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch dochter and German Tochter, from an Indo-European root shared by Greek thugatēr.
- **faugh** |fô| (DATED) - ORIGIN: natural exclamation: first recorded in English in the mid 16th cent.

I found more but they are more or less the same pronunciation, so I decided not to add them.

Comment: Er, maybe I'm missing something here, but it looks like you found the same two pronunciations that snumpy found.

Comment: I guess it's because there aren't other pronunciations existing for "AUGH". Plus he wasn't asking for that only and as you can see I didn't just write the pronunciations.

Comment: @MrHen He found "faugh", which I have only heard pronounced /fɔː/. That is an additional pronunciation.

Comment: @Peter: I am not an expert on the word, but if that is the case than does the answer has the wrong pronunciation?

Comment: @MrHen It would seem so, unless "ô" is being used to represent more than one phoneme.

Comment: In my dictionary it says |fô|, in the OED it says (fɔː). I suppose they are the same? But, @MrHen, I don't think there are words with "AUGH" who have other pronunciations than these I found (and that Snumpy said - considering the question was about "AUGH" and not "vowel + UGH" which has other different pronunciations, obviously), but well, my post was also about the origin. That said, if someone else can find words with different pronunciations I'd like to see them.

Comment: @Alenanno: My original comment was mostly asking for confirmation that I was not missing something: _augh_ appears to be pronounced the same two ways (but now _faugh_ is a potential alteration.)